# how to represent a generic method call in CodeDOM

Tags: c#, codedom

I am trying to write a `CodeAssignStatement` which does something equivalent to the following:

```
this.Foo = row.Field<string>(0);
```

How to write the RHS expression for the `CodeAssignStatement`?

So far I only have:

```
CodeAssignStatement cas = new CodeAssignStatement();
cas.Left = new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), "Foo");
cas.Right = ??!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the `CodeTypeReference` something like this: (Note that I haven't tested this fully, I've just created the graph - not actually rendered it to code)

```
cas.Right = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
    new CodeMethodReferenceExpression(
        new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("row"),
        "Field",
        new CodeTypeReference("System.String")),
    new CodePrimitiveExpression(0));
```

Comment: Just tried it: `GenerateCodeFromStatement` renders exactly the code that's required. :)